# Ant task appears to loop multiple times but I'm not using a loop

Tags: java, ant

My script works, I'm just curious as to why it does this, I don't even have any loops in my script.  The script concats a bunch of js and then minifys it with closure compiler.  Every time a target is hit a message popups just to show that it got hit and where in the process it is.  When I run my script I see it go through the entire script multiple times.  I think it's because of closure compiler when it minifys the js but that's just a guess, has any one else come across something like this?

```
<target name="minify_one"> <!-- depends="delete">-->    
    <echo message="target-concat_one" />
    <concat destfile="${build.dir}/IndexLibrary.js" force="no">
        <fileset dir="${index.dir}">
            <include name="*.js" /> 
            <exclude name="ContentManager.js" />
            <exclude name="MapManager.js" />
            <exclude name="ModuleManager.js" />
            <exclude name="UserManager.js" />
        </fileset> 
    </concat>
</target>

<target name="minify_two" depends="minify_one">
    <echo message="target-concat_two" />
    <concat destfile="${build.dir}/UILibrary.js" force="no">
        <fileset dir="${ui.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.js" />
        </fileset>
    </concat>
</target>

<target name="minify_three" depends="minify_two">   
        <echo message="target-concat_three" />
        <concat destfile="${build.dir}/FrameworkManager.js" force="no">
            <fileset dir="${index.dir}">
                <include name="ContentManager.js" />
                <include name="MapManager.js" />
                <include name="ModuleManager.js" />
                <include name="UserManager.js" />
            </fileset> 
        </concat>
    </target>

<target name="cmd_one" depends="minify_three">
    <echo message="minify IndexLibrary" />
    <exec executable="cmd.exe">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="java -jar compiler.jar --language_in ECMASCRIPT5 --js lib\IndexLibrary.js --js_output_file lib\IndexLibrary.min.js" />
    </exec>
</target>



<target name="cmd_two" depends="cmd_one">
        <echo message="minify UILibrary" />
        <exec executable="cmd.exe">
            <arg value="/c" />
            <arg value="java -jar compiler.jar --language_in ECMASCRIPT5 --js lib\UILibrary.js --js_output_file lib\UILibrary.min.js" /> 
        </exec>
    </target>
<target name="cmd_two" depends="cmd_one">
        <echo message="minify UILibrary" />
        <exec executable="cmd.exe">
            <arg value="/c" />
            <arg value="java -jar compiler.jar --language_in ECMASCRIPT5 --js lib\UILibrary.js --js_output_file lib\UILibrary.min.js" /> 
        </exec>
    </target>

    <target name="cmd_three" depends="cmd_two">
            <echo message="minify FrameworkManager" />
            <exec executable="cmd.exe">
                <arg value="/c" />
                <arg value="java -jar compiler.jar --language_in ECMASCRIPT5 --js lib\FrameworkManager.js --js_output_file lib\FrameworkManager.min.js" />
            </exec>
        </target>
```

This is just a snippet of the code but everything follows this style.

Comment: An Ant script may loop if an ant target calls another target. There is more than one way to do this. Show your code.

Comment: I don't see a reason that any target gets executed multiple times. Can you also post the Ant output when you execute `ant cmd_two`?

Comment: I added cmd_two and cmd_three, they're basically the same thing just with different files.  I couldn't see a reason as to why it loops either, my best guess is because of the cmd commands